# javaagent option does not expand the tilde but why not

Tags: java, linux, javaagents

This invocation works.

`java -ea -cp ~/Documents/workspace/export/testProject1/"*" -javaagent:/home/jack/Documents/workspace/export/testProject1/SizeOf.jar testProject1.Tester`

This invocation fails.

`java -ea -cp ~/Documents/workspace/export/testProject1/"*" -javaagent:~/Documents/workspace/export/testProject1/SizeOf.jar testProject1.Tester`

The failure looks like this.

```
    Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : 
    ~/Documents/workspace/export/testProject1/SizeOf.jar
    Error occurred during initialization of VM
    agent library failed to init: instrument
```

Why does the the `-javaagent` option fail to expand the tilde (`~`). This was on Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tilde is expanded by the shell, not the program being run, and it wasn't at the beginning of the token. Use `"$HOME"` instead.

Comment: Okay, so to contrast, the -classpath or -cp has an argument that has tilde at the beginning of the token so the shell will see it and expand it. Thanks.